# Show price on Braintree's Dropin UI

Tags: ios, braintree

I have an iOS app integrating Braintree's Dropin UI.
When the dropin is showed, the user can hit "pay" button and he is redirected directly to the "Thanks for your order" page.

My problem is I can't find a way to display the price on Braintree's dropin UI. And I know that customers want to see the price again before tapping the button.

I saw nothing in the docs relating to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

The [customization information for the drop-in appearance](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/ios/#customization) is what you're looking for. You can show the price again before they check out by putting it in the Summary or Submit Button.

If you need additional help, feel free to reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).

Comment: Now i feel stupid for not having found this one on my own. Thanks

Comment: do we have something like this for JS-SDK? i tried skimming through the docs but couldn't find anything similar. Can you help ?